# How can I combine the values from one column in rows where another column has duplicate data with Excel Starter?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-office-starter

I may have worded this badly so here is a screenshot:

[image: part numbers and cats]

So in reference to the screenshot I want to combine the three rows I have highlighted. That data from the column I pointed to should be concatenated while the data from the first column should be merged (not sure if this is the correct terminology).

To use a simpler example: I have

```
Animal   Attribute
cat      mammal
cat      furry
cat      quadruped
canary   bird
canary   yellow
```

and I want to get

```
Animal   Attribute
cat      mammal|furry|quadruped
canary   bird|yellow
```

I am using Excel Starter 2010 so I would like to do this with a formula if possible.

Thanks.

Comment: I have edited your question to show an example of the output that you seem to be asking for. Is this right? Or do you want, for instance, commas between the values from the second column? Please re-edit the question, as necessary, to provide further clarification.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. I would like the combined output separated with a pipe and I have edited my question accordingly. I have actually figured out how to do this but have not had enough time to post my answer yet.

Comment: I found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15756028/2097294

Comment: Scott, how should I handle this since I found my answer from that of another question?

Comment: I would say: post it as an answer, giving credit to the source. (You might need to wait a few more hours before you can answer your own question. After you have posted the answer, you can then accept it – possibly after [another?] delay of several hours – and earn yourself some rep points, and maybe a badge or two.) But that’s just my answer; I don’t speak for Super User.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was this answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15756028/2097294 which involved using the following formula: `=IF(A2=A1,C1&", "&B2,B2)` to concatenate all the attributes for each entry and `=IF(A3<>A2,0,1)` to mark each row with either a `1` or a `0`. Then I sorted by that column and deleted all the rows with a `1` in that column, leaving me with just the rows with all the  attribute values concatenated in one column.